# Facebook Login Issue not able to get the response code

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

We need to get the code in the response but not able to get the response_type = code? Why Below is my code:

```
FB.login(function(response){
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    }, {scope: 'public_profile,email', response_type: 'code', redirect_uri: 'https://loc.blog.com/facebooklogin.php'});
```

Getting the below Response but not code:

```
accessToken: "XXXXXXXXXXX"
userID: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
expiresIn: XXXX
signedRequest: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
graphDomain: "facebook"
data_access_expiration_time: XXXx
```

Comment: I don’t think you can specify the response_type when using FB.login, that is only for when you implement https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

Comment: Thanks for give this solution but I found the solution. Actually we need the code which FB is already given in singedRequest response param. Basically it is a jwt token. which we can decode and use it. On the server end we need to pass blank as the call back ur.